# How do you use npm in Visual studio 2017 without project.json file?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2017

Now that they removed project.json in Visual Studio 2017, but npm used to install packages in the devDependencies in that file, how do we use npm to install packages now? If I create a package.json file, wouldn't that be redundant considering the existing MyProject.csproj file?

Comment: Good question. Stuck with the same problem here

Comment: I ended up using npm init and it added package.json in the root folder as always. We can still install things using npm and it will be in the package.json file. If you want to do something like adding "precompile" in project.json, now we have to do it in the .csproj file. Here's how it works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj

Answer (score 1):

When you install library via terminal and click on dependencies in the solution project, you can see that library will be marked as **extraneous**.

**Extraneous** means a package is installed but is not listed in your project's package.json

So use package.json if you want to install packages.